# Cookies null on some pages but not others

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, cookies

I am working on a site that has some shared code across all pages for navigation.  In the shared code, I am reading a cookie that determines which navigation to display.  (Different customers get a different experience).  When the cookie is set, I can navigate from page to page and use the cookie to determine which navigation to show so the customer always sees the same navigation on every page.  This works flawlessly on all 13 pages except 2.  For some reason, it always returns a null when reading the cookie but if I go back to one of the other pages, the cookie still exists.  I am quite confused by this considering it is the exact same piece of code reading the cookie on all pages.  Any ideas why this could be happening?

Thanks,

Rhonda

```
if (_httpContext != null && _httpContext.Request.Cookies["MyNav"] != null)
        {
            HttpCookie navigationCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["MyNav"];
            topNavDlpCatIdFromCookie = navigationCookie != null &&
                                        Int32.TryParse(navigationCookie["categoryId"], out topNavDlpCatId)
                                            ? topNavDlpCatId
                                            : 0;
        }
```

Comment: Do you have the code where you are setting the cookie?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a problem with the cookies "path" property. Maybe when you write the cookie to the client, you set the "path" to a sub folder on server. And your 2 pages are stored outside that folder. For example, when you write cookie:

```
Response.AppendCookie(new HttpCookie("MyNav","yourvalue"){path = "/folder1"});
```

And your other 2 pages are stored on `"/folder2"`. In this case, the browser will not send the cookie for these 2 pages, that's why you get null on server side.